# HerokuからS3に画像をアップできません。

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, heroku, amazon-s3

iOSからS3に画像をアップしたいです。本番環境はHerokuに置いてあり、画像だけをS3に保存したいです。開発はRailsで行っており、libraryはpaperclipを用いています。リンク先を参考にしましたが"status code: 500, headers"というエラーが帰ってくる状況です。 https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3

未だ問題点の特定が出来ておりません。アドバイスあればご教示いただきたいです。

```
#terminal
$heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME="kenja.jp"
$heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=my_access_key_id
$heroku config:set AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=my_secret_access_key

#app/models/user.rb
has_attached_file :photo, 
  :styles => { medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" },
  :storage => :s3,
  :bucket => 'kenja.jp',
  :s3_permissions => :public,
  :url => ":s3_domain_url",
  :path => "/assets/photos/:id/:style/:basename.:extension",
  :s3_host_name => "s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com",
  :s3_credentials => :"#{Rails.root}/config/s3.yml"


#config/environments/staging.rb
config.paperclip_defaults = {
  :storage => :s3,
  :s3_credentials => {
    :bucket => ENV['kenja.jp'],
    :access_key_id => ENV['my_access_key_id'],
    :secret_access_key => ENV['my_secret_access_key']
  }
}


#config/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:url] = ':s3_domain_url'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:path] ='/:class/:attachment/:id/:style.:extenstion'
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com'


#app/apis/v1/users.rb
  params do  
    requires :id, type:Integer
    requires :icon, type:Rack::Multipart::UploadedFile
  end
  post '/post_picture' do
    photo_file = ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile.new(params[:icon])
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.update(photo: photo_file)
    @user.photo
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

500エラーなのでサーバー側（Rails側）でなんらかのエラーが発生しているんだと思います。

Herokuのサーバーログを見ると詳細なエラーメッセージやスタックトレースが載っているはずです。まずそれを確認してください。
エラーメッセージやスタックトレースをじっくり確認すれば、この問題も自己解決するかもしれません。
解決した場合は原因と解決策を自分で回答してください。

解決しなければログの内容と、解決のために自分で試してみたことを追記してください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。エラーメッセージを確認致します。

Answer (score 1):

heroku logsで確認したところ以下のエラーが確認できました。

```
2015-10-18T06:33:10.144859+00:00 app[web.1]:  app/apis/v1/users.rb:112:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Users>'
2015-10-18T06:33:10.144858+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant Paperclip::Storage::S3::AWS):
2015-10-18T06:33:10.128265+00:00 app[web.1]:  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 15]]
```

リンク先を確認したところ、以下のようにすればよかったようです。

```
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 2.0'
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374401/nameerror-uninitialized-constant-paperclipstorages3aws

Comment: 無事解決したようで良かったです。自分で承認できるようになったら(48時間経ったら)、回答の承認もよろしくお願いします。 [自分の質問に回答できますか? - ヘルプ センター - スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: アドバイス誠にありがとうございました。明日承認を行います。